# Can't add MoPub SDK in my project

Tags: android, sdk, mopub

When I add MoPub SDK in my project I get much errors. 
[image]

This is fragments from my **build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
...
compile project(':mopub-sdk')
...
```

}

and **settings.gradle**

```
include ':mopub-sdk'
```

Comment: Are you still having problems with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have integrated the full bundle of the MoPub SDK which contains the Millennial Media adapter but not the Millennial Media SDK.

You can resolve this issue by removing the Millennial Media adapters or by integrating the SDK.

If you decide to keep the adapter and integrate Millennial, you will have to add the dependency for the third party ad network adapter as well.

The adapters are named:
MillennialBanner.java
MillennialInterstitial.java

To integrate the Millennial Media, include the SDK.

Here is the link under 2. to integrate the Millennial Media SDK from the MoPub documentation on integrating third party ad networks.
https://github.com/mopub/mopub-android-sdk/wiki/Integrating-Third-Party-Ad-Networks#2-link-the-third-party-sdks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have copied the **mopub-sdk** directory in the root of your project folder. So you should have a structure like:

```
module1/
module2/
mopub-sdk/
```

Then just make sure to do "Sync Project with Gradle", "Clean" and "Build" freshly and you should be good to go.